# Laravel Model Factory get Same ID

Tags: php, laravel-5, illuminate-container

How to get the same model id i tried this not working.

```
$factory->define(App\Item::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'color' => $faker->color_name,
        'position' => App\Item::all()->get('id'),
    ];
});
```

I want to get the same id for the item so that the item position is the same when the application runs and can be edited to something (integer only).

Comment: What's the reasoning behind `App\Item::all()->get('id')` ?

Comment: I want to make the `position` same as the `id`.